# Is Non Penetrative Pre-Marital sex allowed in Hinduism?

Tags: marriage, sin, sex, hell

1. Let's say
   Me and A Girl did hook-up/ 1 night stand .. we did all kind of sexual activities, But Not Penetration & Not Blowjob

So Is this a sin ? Since sexual intercourse wasn't performed... Is there any hell told for it

2. Also is sexual intercourse allowed with future wife ?(Will marry her in future.. but sex earlier)